# Div goes up when the browser window shrinks

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I would like the div (home) to be in the middle of the page and that the footer always stays down. The problem however is that when I now shrink the browser window, that the div moves to the top

And I use Bootstrap 5

Excuse my bad English, I hope I could bring it across reasonably understandable

CODE: https://jsfiddle.net/odbefhLy/

```css
.navbar {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    border-top: 2px solid #5f8dd3;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.home {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logo {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 5px solid #5f8dd3;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.text h1, h6 {
    color: var(--font-color);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    height: 55px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--font-color);

    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="home">
      <img class="logo d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="https://duckduckgo.com/assets/common/dax-logo.svg" alt="LOGO">
       <div class="text">
          <h1>TEST</h1>
          <h6>BLABLABLABLABLA</h6>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>

<div class="container">
  <footer class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center py-3 my-4 border-top">
    <p class="col-md-4 mb-0 text-muted">&copy; 2021 Company, Inc</p>

    <a href="/" class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto link-dark text-decoration-none">
      <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"/></svg>
    </a>

    <ul class="nav col-md-4 justify-content-end">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}

.container .home {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    border-top: 2px solid #5f8dd3;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*CHANGED*/
.home {
}

/*CHANGED*/
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.logo {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 5px solid #5f8dd3;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.text h1, h6 {
    color: var(--font-color);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

/*CHANGED*/
footer {
    height: 55px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--font-color);
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- CHANGED -->
<div class="container flex-grow-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="home">
      <img class="logo d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="https://duckduckgo.com/assets/common/dax-logo.svg" alt="LOGO">
       <div class="text">
          <h1>TEST</h1>
          <h6>BLABLABLABLABLA</h6>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>

<div class="container">
  <footer class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center py-3 my-4 border-top">
    <p class="col-md-4 mb-0 text-muted">&copy; 2021 Company, Inc</p>

    <a href="/" class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto link-dark text-decoration-none">
      <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"/></svg>
    </a>

    <ul class="nav col-md-4 justify-content-end">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: It still moves up and the footer doesn't always stay down all the time

Comment: https://prnt.sc/5bpAuGpZ6UPJ 
Is this expected behavior?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/T0ssHvj.png - If you make the browser window smaller at the bottom, it will move to the top. The window doesn't go over things, if you know what I mean